# Reading all request url using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get all the request URLs that gets loaded when a page loads.
I want to achieve this using Jquery. I have searched for it but all I got was finding request URL for the current page .I want all request URLs.
Please guide.

Comment: It’s not possible using client-side javascript. You need to log it on the server and then do an ajax request from the client to retrieve the log.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to work on $.get() because it has to complete event.

I suggest to use $.ajax() like this,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.org',
    data: {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
    dataType: 'xml',
    complete : function(){
        alert(this.url);// here you can apply array globally  and push all url then you will get all urls 
    },
    success: function(xml){
    }
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/Tu6Zr/84/)**